# how do i prompt a user to re enter their input value, if the value is invalid?

Tags: java

```
public int inputNumber() { 
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of cookies you'd like to make ");
    int number = input.nextInt();
    if (number <=0) {
       System.out.println(" please enter a valid number")
       int number = input.nextInt(); 
    }
    input.close();
    return number;
}
```

EDIT:

I should have used a while loop.. throwback to literally my first project.

Comment: What's with the random downvote? This is a totally legitimate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
System.out.print("Enter the number of cookies you'd like to make:");
int number = input.nextInt();

while(number<=0) //As long as number is zero or less, repeat prompting
{
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid number:");
    number = input.nextInt();    
}
```

This is about data validation. It can be done with a `do-while` loop or a `while` loop. You can read up on topics of using loops.

**Remarks on your codes:**
You shouldn't declare `number` twice. That is doing `int` `number` more than once in your above codes (which is within same scope).

Comment: This is too much unless you are required to have the "Please enter a valid number" print statement. With a do-while loop, you could cut out the superfluous print statement, and it would still handle your data validation.

Comment: @user3270760 Pls kindly re-read the OP's question. He might want an error message upon receiving bad inputs and not just continuous prompting the same message when input is wrong.

Comment: @ user3437460 Good call, my apologies.

Answer (score 2):

This way you have fewer superfluous print statements and you don't need to declare you variable multiple times.

```
public int inputNumber() {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int number = 0;

    do {
        System.out.print("Enter the number of cookies you'd like to make ");
        number = input.nextInt();
    } while(number <= 0);

    input.close();
    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues:

1. You are missing semicolon in you println method.
2. You are redefining the number within if
3. you are using if which is for checking number instead use while so until and unless user enters correct number you dont proceed.

   ```
   public int inputNumber() { 
   Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter the number of cookies you'd like to make ");
   int number = input.nextInt();
   while (number <=0) {
      System.out.println(" please enter a valid number");
      number = input.nextInt(); 
   }
   input.close();
   return number;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The classical way of doing that is to limit the number of retry and abort beyond that ::

```
static final int MAX_RETRY = 5; // what you want
...
int max_retry = MAX_RETRY;
int number;
while (--max_retry >= 0) {
    System.out.print("Enter the number of cookies you'd like to make ");
    number = input.nextInt();
    if (number > 0) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid number")
}
if (max_retry == 0) {
    // abort
    throw new Exception("Invalid input");
}
// proceed with number ...
```